# How to add react-native-fs to a project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

I have a simple project to which I want to add react-native-fs library. I've followed various tutorials that say to do this in the terminal:

`npm install react-native-fs --save`

and then to

`react-native link react-native-fs` which seems to no longer work, and now instead you're supposed to do

`npx react-native-asset` based on [Unrecognized command "link" when linking fonts in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872203/unrecognized-command-link-when-linking-fonts-in-react-native)

I did all of this, and can see that react-native-fs is in my package.json, as well as a bunch of changes in package-lock.json. Except that as soon as I add `import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'` to one of my views, my application won't load anymore, it's just a blank page. This is after I do `npm start`.

Here's what the view looks like

```
import { Text, SafeAreaView, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Separator from './fragments/Separator';
//import RNFS from 'react-native-fs' --> this is the line that breaks the App

const ReplayScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
      <Text>Replay Screen</Text>
  )
}

export default ReplayScreen;
```

Any ideas what's causing the problem or how to correctly add react-native-fs to a project?

Comment: What is your react-native version ?

Comment: @monim in package.json it says `"react-native": "^0.71.3"`

Comment: according to doc **For RN >= 0.61 please install react-native-fs at version >= @2.16.0!** so make sure you are using **react-native-fs at version >= @2.16.0!**

Comment: @monim I am using react-native-fs version 2.20.0

Comment: I have solved my problem. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74096927/react-native-fs-not-working-on-react-native-version-0-69

Answer (score 0):

I spent way too long trying to setup react-native-fs yesterday so here are a few things I can think of that you might want to check :

- That you have the correct version of react-native-fs for your version of RN (though I see in the comments you've already checked)
- That you've followed all the setup steps listed in the docs for the platform you're planning on using.
- Try running the app with `npx react-native run-android` or `npx react-native run-ios`
- When setting it up I found that the changes I made in MainApplication.java per the docs' instructions (for Android setup) were causing an error, and I needed to remove those changes to get it to work.

Not sure if any of this will help but hopefully something will, best of luck